# How do I dismiss just the next occurrence of a recurring alarm?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, alarm

Tomorrow is a Bank Holiday in the UK so I don't want my "Work" alarm to go off. I could turn the whole alarm off, but then I'd have to remember to turn it back on again before I go to bed on Monday night. Or I could turn off Monday's occurrence, but again I'd have to remember to reinstate it before next Monday.

So what I'd like to do is just dismiss the next occurrence of the alarm. A Google search came up with this help page - https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840926?hl=en-GB :

> #### Dismiss next alarm
>
> If you have an alarm that's set to repeat, you can dismiss the next instance of the alarm. That way your alarm will still be turned on for future instances.

Which describes exactly what I want to do. It goes on to list the procedure as:

> 1. Open the Clock app. [image: Clock]
> 2. At the top, touch the alarm clock iconalarm.
> 3. Under the alarm you want to dismiss, touch "Dismiss Now" dismiss alarm.

However, I'm not seeing the "Dismiss Now" option.

Where is it or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just discovered that Google have added a "Pause alarm" function to their standard clock [since version 7.3](https://crast.net/178710/google-clock-7-3-brings-two-important-improvements-so-that-the-alarm-only-rings-when-you-need-it/):

[image: Screenshot of the Google clock alarm function showing the Pause alarm funtion]
[image: Screenshot of the Google clock alarm function showing the calendar to select the dates to pause the alarm for]

It allows the alarm to be paused for a range of dates at any point in the future, not just for the next occurrence of the alarm.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** since version 7.3, Google Clock allows [pausing repeating alarms](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/248765/44325). Below explanation is only for historical purpose.

---

It was impossible to dismiss the next repeating alarm, and looks like the help page was different.

Cross-checking with the [help support in English (US)](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840926?hl=en), and for the same topic, it instead mentions,

> #### Dismiss next alarm
>
> If you have an alarm **scheduled to go off within the next two hours**, you can dismiss the next instance of your alarm. *If your alarm is set to repeat, your alarm will still be turned on for future instances*.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

The alarm can only be dismissed if it goes off in 2 hours (like for other alarms), but for repeating alarm, Android will set the next alarm automatically.

---

This issue has been reported on [Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/HtQq0fqs8Z0;context-place=forum/nexus).

Comment: I tried to add a reply there, but got an error. Is there a procedure for making feature requests at all?

Comment: @ChrisF not sure why you can't reply, you have to be logged-in with Google account though. As for feature request, I'm not sure either if they accept it, but that forum is for Google apps and Nexus in general. For stock Android OS (AOSP), you should post it on [Android Issue Tracker](http://b.android.com) though.

Comment: My Samsung S7 (running 6.0.1) doesn't seem to have the "Dismiss Now" option. Do you know if there's a way to do this with Marshmallow?

Comment: @TripeHound this question is actually talking about Nexus stock clock app, which is [Google's Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock). As for other stock clock app (e.g. on Samsung, etc), I'm afraid I can't help because the vendor may customize and provide their own clock app...

Comment: Thanks. It looks like Samsung have (they seem to do this a lot).

Answer (score 4):

Add a do not disturb rule for the duration. Not a complete solution, but that's what I do.

Comment: That's a good workaround. Your answer could be improved if you add instructions for how to do that. Maybe the questioner has never used the do-not-disturb feature.

Comment: The problem with Do Not Disturb is that it silences phone calls as well as alarms. Definitely not a solution for me

Comment: this doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered this alarm clock app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep&hl=en_GB

One of it's features is the integration with Google Calendar:

http://sleep.urbandroid.org/documentation/integration/google-calendar/

The two relevant features are:

> - your alarms can be automatically disabled for public holidays
> - your alarms can take your calendar events into account

This will do what I'm looking for, though I'm not sure I want my holidays on my Google calendar for all and sundry to see.

Answer (score 0):

Check my app on Android playstore - [Alarm + Task Logger PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobitronix.gauravchauhan.alarmplus.pro)

It has skip next next functionality for recurring alarms. You can skip any number of upcoming occurences.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Galaxy S6 I open the clock, choose Alarm at the bottom, then tap the slider on the repeating alarm to turn it off. A prompt appears below the alarm asking to Turn on again . Tap this prompt. Will turn on again appears on alarm.

[tag: V11]