# Can I dismiss an upcoming alarm on standard Samsung S7?

Tags: alarm, samsung-galaxy-s7

On a Samsung S7 (running 6.0.1) with standard apps, is there a way of "pre-dismissing" the next occurrence of a repeating alarm without turning the alarm off altogether?

I have a regular alarm set to wake me up in the morning. Sometimes, I'll wake shortly before the alarm is due to go off. In effect I want to say "*I'm up, don't sound the alarm this morning*" without turning it off completely and having to remember to turn it back on again before I go to sleep.

Note, this question "[How do I dismiss just the next occurrence of a recurring alarm?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/143845/115134)" and its answer concern the stock Nexus clock app. However, I'm asking about whether this can be done using the Samsung stock app.

Comment: This feature is not there on Samsung devices

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks. I suspected not, but just in case I'd missed an option somewhere...

Comment: I don't own a Samsung device but that's what a fairly thorough Internet search tells me, including features of latest models

Comment: [Timely](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely) does that

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Recurring task reminder FREE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobitronix.gauravchauhan.alarmplus.free)

It has more recurring reminder, filter & customization options than other apps in play store.

Comment: Your other answers makes mention of this same app but they do at least note that you are its owner. You did not do so here which may be treated as an attempt to SPAM the site. Moreover, all of them are just link-only. Please provide some details, such as how to achieve the objective in question.

Comment: Replying to @Firelord I acknowledge I am the app owner & apologize for being too brief. My app has a "skip next" feature for recurring alarms, using which an upcoming alarm can be skipped without dismissing the alarm altogether.